# Laravel Nova - How to filter BelongsTo field choices when creating a new record?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have a branch, branch_products, and invoices, and invoice_products models.

branch has many branch_products, 
branch has many invoices,

invoices has many invoice_products
branch_products has many invoice_products

Now going back to the question,
When creating a new invoice product, I want the BelongsTo field to only show me branch products that is in the branch of the invoice.

```
// InvoiceProduct.php

public function invoice() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Invoice');
}

public function branchProduct() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\BranchProduct');
}

// I need something like this
public function getAvailableBranchProducts() {

    // get the branch id of the invoice, doesn't work
    $branchId = $this->invoice->branch_id;

    // get branch products that has the given branch id, doesn't work
    return whereHas('branch_products', function ($query) use ($branchId) {
        $query->where('branch_id', $branchId);
    })->get();
}
```

I don't know how I would solve this. I've tried WhereHas, local scopes, but no luck.

I need it for Laravel Nova.

Comment: When you are __Going To Create a Invoice Product__ there is no relationship for that, Because Invoice Product is not created yet. It's yet to be created. Do you understand.

Comment: So is there no way to filter the branch products to only show branch products of the branch of the invoice?

Comment: You have to reconsider about your project design, I guess you are trying to create a new invoice and assign products to the invoice. May be you are selecting the 'Branch' first. So my advice is to When user select the Branch get the 'Branch Products' using an AJAX call and fill into 'Products' select box.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method inside of the Nova resource:

For example, if you had a BelongsTo field of users and needed to filter them by their type, you could add this method:

```php
    public static function relatableUsers(NovaRequest $request, $query){
        return $query->where('type', 'editor');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have probably solved this already, but there is a package that adds a Nova field that could help you (or others reaching this page).

https://packagist.org/packages/orlyapps/nova-belongsto-depend

Quite simple to install and use. You can use it or get some ideas from it.